# No response to POST from webUI to Node.JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest

I'm hitting a brick wall trying to understand the disconnect between the Ajax POST to Node.JS and the express() response to it.. For example:

Client:

```
var posting = $.post( "http://localhost:3000/put/requestList" , { first_name: "John", last_name: "Mensa", gender : "Male" })
    .done(function( data ) {
  $( "#schemesdisplay" ).append("Response sent!");
});
```

Server:

```
//configure body-parser for express
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//allow express to access our html (index.html) file
app.get('/ui/index.html', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "index.html");
});
app.post('/put/requestList', function(req, res){
 response = {
  first_name : req.body.first_name,
  last_name : req.body.last_name,
  gender: req.body.gender
 };
 res.end(JSON.stringify(response + "Server Responds!"));
});
var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
var host = server.address().address;
var port = server.address().port;
console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

In my server's console, I can see the data submitted by the client. However, there is no indication that the server has responded, let alone how to get it back into the div I need the response to be in.

Ideally, I need to send JSON blocks from UI to Node.JS server and back. However getting this simple communication up with two totally different environments has proven to be a challenge.

Any (helpful) suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace this line

```
res.end(JSON.stringify(response + "Server Responds!"));
```

with this

```
res.json(response);
```

res.end() will end the response process. This method actually comes from Node core, specifically the response.end() method of http.ServerResponse. It is used to quickly end the response without any data.

You may also need to change your jQuery post code to include the headers to post json:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/put/requestList",
    data: JSON.stringify({ first_name: "John", last_name: "Mensa", gender : "Male" }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        $( "#schemesdisplay" ).append("Response sent!");
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        $( "#schemesdisplay" ).append("ERROR!");
    }
});
```

Comment: I replaced that line.. still getting the output on server, but nothing to indicate any response on UI at all.. :/

Comment: What are you seeing in Chrome Dev Console. Is the request being made in the network tab?

Comment: @Poder I have updated my answer with something extra to try.

Comment: Looks like a cross-scripting error. I'm running requests from an embedded webserver at port 81 to the node.js server on port 81/3000 through the same package.. what now >.<

Comment: I replaced it with your $.ajax statement, and replaced JSON with JSONP. Now I'm getting a 404, and the node.js server doesn't say anything what-so-ever. The 404 is coming through chrome dev tools.. ":Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Interestingly enough, dev-tools is also showing it as a GET rather than a POST for some reason.. not sure why as the type was left as "POST"..

Comment: You can't make a JSONP post. You can only do a JSONP GET request. You will have to set up CORS if you are going to make cross-domain posts. Have a look at https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Comment: Was able to see the possibility of adding jsonp with POST and adding the cross domain option. Server sees something now but doesn't get data, still not seeing any kind of output on the UI at all. This is strange. Almost 3am and racking brain over this!

Comment: JSON-P only works because you're allowed to insert <script> tags into the DOM, and they can point anywhere, but that only allows GET requests for that reason. You will have to use CORS